# Blazor Standalone WASM - Cannot fetch roles

Tags: blazor, webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I've created a standalone Blazor WASM. I'm using authentication and authorization services. Roles are configured as this (excerpt from app manifest in Azure):

`"..."` = intentionally removed

```
"id": "b143bedd-b16c-4b94-...",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "ec351a0b-19d7-...",
"appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Handledare kan lägga till och ta bort sessioner i kurser",
        "displayName": "Handledare",
        "id": "583f0ed6-1f22-4712-8d23-d438f2411cf5",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "Sessions.CRUD"
    },
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Samordnare kan lägga till och ta bort kursdeltagare",
        "displayName": "Samordnare",
        "id": "3d7c144a-f87f-4806-a8c5-0ba9cca13c9f",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "User.EnrolUnenrol"
    }
```

In my Program.cs I have configured authentication/authorization as this:

```
builder.Services
            .AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes
                    .Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
                options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
                options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";
            });

        builder.Services
            .AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Samordnare", policy =>
                    policy.RequireRole("User.EnrolUnenrol"));
                options.AddPolicy("Handledare", policy =>
                    policy.RequireRole("Sessions.CRUD"));

            });
```

In NavMenu.razor I have added policy checks as this:

```
<MudNavMenu>
<MudNavLink Href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Home">Start</MudNavLink>
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <MudNavLink Href="/enrolme" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person">Mina kursanmälningar</MudNavLink>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Policy="Samordnare">
    <Authorized>
        <MudDivider Class="my-2" />
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2" Class="px-4 mud-text-secondary">Samordnare</MudText>
        <MudDivider Class="my-2" />
        <MudNavLink Href="/manageenrolments" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.People">Hantera andras kursanmälningar</MudNavLink>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

When I launch the application and log in I get the following auth error:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
  Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
  RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (User.EnrolUnenrol)
```

(I have assigned myself to the Samordnare(User.EnrolUnenrol) role in AAD)

If I F12 and check my session info in Edge I can see that the roles are fetched.

```
    {
  "aud": "...",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../v2.0",
  "iat": ...,
  "nbf": ...,
  "exp": ...,
  "groups": [
    ...
  ],
  "name": "Peter Rundqvist",
  "nonce": "...",
  "oid": "...",
  "preferred_username": "peter.rundqvist@...",
  "rh": "...",
  "roles": [
    "User.EnrolUnenrol",
    "Sessions.CRUD"
  ],
  "sub": "...",
  "tid": "...",
  "uti": "...",
  "ver": "2.0",
  "wids": [
    "...",
    "..."
  ]
}
```

So, as far as I can see, the claims are sent to the browser. But, why doesn't my Policy get this? Shouldn't `options.AddPolicy("Samordnare", policy => policy.RequireRole("User.EnrolUnenrol"));` map "User.EnrolUnenrol" to "Samordnare" and make it possible to use `<AuthorizeView Policy="Samordnare">`?

What am I doing wrong here?

Kind reagards,
Peter

Comment: Try to check the roles loaded for the user by the Identity. I think that the Identity doesn't load properly the _roles_ into the User object.

Answer (score 0):

I might be simply a case of missing an .RequireAuthenticatedUser() on the policy.

For the sake of simplicity, I've set it on the fallback policy, but you can place it on any of your policies.

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                   .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
}
```

In case that does not work - meaning your user is still able to access all of the pages - I think you need to read the Microsoft Docs on [WebAssembly standalone MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-accounts?view=aspnetcore-5.0), from there you'll be able to retrace the steps in your app and find out if you're missing more crucial features.